# Unable to install Bleachbit (or any software) using either command line or Software interface

Tags: dependencies, bleachbit

first time poster but I've been using Linux for a while but I'm far from grasping the operating system.  Any time there's an error that pops up when I'm doing stuff, it crashes my brain because I haven't a clue what to do.

With that said, I'm trying to install bleachbit (or any software) for that matter and it seems I keep getting the same errors.  For example, I'm trying to install bleachbit via terminal and here's what I get:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo apt install bleachbit
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                            linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$
```

If I try via the Software interface, I get:

```
Unable to install Bleachbit: Error while installing package: installed linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I'm running version 22.04.

I would love to know how to fix this.  I checked devices and locations and it says I have 212.2 GB available on ubuntu-desktop.

[Screenshot of df - h;df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcw8H.png)

This is what happens if I try to do the command:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
```

[sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD9Aw.png)

If I try the command:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic
```

[sudo apt install linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6CSZ.png)

Lastly if I try:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

[sudo apt full-upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfwqc.png)

Here is [df -h;df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJkZ.png)

Here is apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]'

> ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]'
> linux-generic-hwe-22.04
> linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic
> linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic

Comment: did you try `apt --fix-broken install`, as the message suggested?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu release please?

Comment: How do I find out what version I'm using?  And yes, I tried that command and I get the same out come after I do that.

Comment: Found it!  i'm using ubuntu for desktop: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Maybe running out of space? [edit] your question and show us `df - h;df -i` please

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first before you install stuff. When you fail to do this, you can run into problems like this because the packages being fetched won't match the outdated package list on your computer.

Comment: Also, have you tried running: `sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic` and then `sudo apt install linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic`? Also also, `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions.  I updated the original post.

Comment: I'm sorry,  the last time I was with my mobil here and oversaw a space. Please [edit] your question and add `df -h` also `apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]'` as text in codeblock not as image. thank''s

Comment: Updated my original post.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P linux-generic-hwe-22.04  linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-25-generic` Make sure you has all default repository enabled https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories  then try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04`

Comment: I think I may have to reinstall Ubuntu.  None of these ideas are working.  I can't even install anything new anymore.